# Regular Expression for validatin version numbers using asp RegularExpressionValidator control

Tags: asp.net, regex

I need regular expression for validating version number using asp.net RegularExpressionValidator control. Please find below valid and invalid version numbers

Valid

1.1

1.1.3.4

1.0

1.1.334

Invalid

1

1.

1..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use a regular expression for this. Rather use .NET's [`Version`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx) type:

```
Version v;
if (Version.TryParse(input, out v)) {
  // Valid
} else {
  // Not valid.
}
```

For more details (eg. ensuing there is more than one component to the version you can use the properties of the `Version` instance).

EDIT: To do this client side in JavaScipt, there is no such helper, but based on your examples something like:

```
^\d+(\.\d+)+$
```

should work.

Comment: But I need regular expression to validate at client end. Since the version numbers will be entered in a textbox

Comment: @user166013 Please revise the question to ask more precisely what you want (client side in JavaScript).